# Check if WC Command output is greather than in BASH

Tags: linux, bash, wc

I need to check if wc command output is greather than a variable. Here's my code:

```
if test wc -w $i -gt $num
then
   echo "too great"
fi
```

If the current file $i contains more words than the $num variable i print "too great". I already tried all but can't get the script working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to take the output of the `wc` command and use it as an argument to `test`:

```
if test "$( wc -w < "$i" )" -gt "$num"
```

See "Command Substitution" in `man bash`.

If you don't use redirection `<`, `wc` also outputs the file name, which would break the comparison.